# ng-Show and ng-Hide Divisions on ng-repeat values

Tags: angularjs

```
<html>
    <span ng-init="hideTableDiv = false;"></span>
    <div ng-repeat="schedule in allschedules" ng-if="(schedule.faculty_id==row.faculty_id) && (schedule.start_time)=='09:30:00'">
       <span ng-init="hideTableDiv = true;"></span>
       <span id="{{schedule.schedule_id}}" style="font-size: 88%">   

           <span class="label spanlabel" style="font-weight:100">{{schedule.classroom}}&nbsp;{{schedule.module_name}}&nbsp;{{schedule.cohort_name}}</span>
           <a id="delete_0-{{$index}}" class="" ng-click="deleteschedule(schedule.start_time,schedule.module_id,schedule.schedule_id);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color:red"></i></a>           

       </span>      
   </div>
   <div ng-if="!hideTableDiv">ALL DROPDOWN BOXES</div>
</html>
```

Glimpse of my code i am working on. Need to check if labeldiv is shown hide table div and vice versa.

How that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

do it like this:

```
<html>
<span ng-init="hideTableDiv = false;"></span>
<div id="labeldiv" ng-repeat="schedules in allschedules" ng-if="schedules.facultyis==row.facultyid">
<span ng-init="hideTableDiv = true;"></span>
<span>id Matches</span>
</div>

<div id="tablediv"  ng-if="!hideTableDiv">
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Need to hide tablediv if labeldiv ng-if conditions matches

Comment: Yeah thats what this code does, if ng-if is true then hideTableDiv  becomes true and tabldiv will be hidden

Comment: actual id is lbeldiv_0-{{index}} and tablediv_0-{{index}}, so that those be unique, ng-if is giving error

Comment: <div id="tablediv_0-{{index}}" ng-if="!hidetablediv_0-{{index}}"> Something like this

Comment: id is not associated with angular, please update your question with this updated code you shared in comment.

Comment: the code looks good, what is the  error in your console or page?

Comment: there's no error but the end result is both the divs are visible